# JS indexOf array of objects and splice() not removing the correct object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vuex

I have an array of objects like so:

```
"followers": [
        {
            "id": "1be87842-2f7f-4e3b-8fde-9a998feb3a01",
            "bug_id": "4ae2707b-07ef-4e07-95da-77855c67fece",
            "user_id": "e9e81aa2-4994-483d-a3a7-3b88491f1fda",
            "username": "texample1",
            "name": "Test Example1",
            "created_at": "2018-11-27 21:01:42",
            "updated_at": "2018-11-27 21:01:42",
            "deleted_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": "7bd1fa5f-4109-4beb-b53a-fb03a1d23536",
            "bug_id": "4ae2707b-07ef-4e07-95da-77855c67fece",
            "user_id": "e9e81aa2-4994-483d-a3a7-3b88491f1fda",
            "username": "texample1",
            "name": "Test Example2",
            "created_at": "2018-11-27 21:01:48",
            "updated_at": "2018-11-27 21:01:48",
            "deleted_at": null
        }
    ]
```

and I am attempting to remove one object by it's index with the following code in my vuex store:

```
  let followersArray = state.bugs.find(b => b.id === follower.bug_id).followers
  let index = followersArray.indexOf(follower)
  followersArray.splice(index, 1)
```

I am passing an entire follower object through to this mutation, then finding the followers array on the bug object, finding the index and attempting to splice it from the full bug object's array of follower objects. This code removes another follower from the bug. The index logs as -1 and it should be 1. Anyone see what I'm missing here? If I could get the correct index, I would also add an `if(index !== -1))` in there.

Comment: if you use `"followers": {}` instead of `"followers": []` you can name the keys which would make grabbing by index simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `findIndex()` function and return  the index of the follower based on his id :

```
      let index = followersArray.findIndex(i => i.id === follower.id);
```

**Example** :

```js
let items = [{
  name: "aaa"
}, {
  name: "bbb"
}, {
  name: "ccc"
}];
let c = {
  name: "ccc"
};
let index = items.findIndex(item => item.name === c.name)

console.log(index)
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution. +1

Comment: That worked. The objects are slightly different, so finding index by id works best. Thanks!

Comment: @HusamIbrahim thank you very much, and i don't understand why someone downvote my answer, if there's something went wrong with my answer he could mention that in comment

Answer (score 2):

When you run this code and it returns a `-1`:

`let index = followersArray.indexOf(follower);`

that means that the `follower` object is not contained in `followersArray`. The `followersArray` likely contains a copy of the `follower` object -- not a reference to the same object.

Even if the `follower` object has the same attributes and attribute values as the object in `followersArray[1]`, the `indexOf` will return a `-1` unless they are the same exact object.

Now if you just want to find an object in the array with a matching attribute value (such as `id`) then you could use `map` or `findIndex` to do so:

`let index = followersArray.map(i => i.id).indexOf(follower.id);`

Answer (score 0):

If you print the result of followersArray in the console what does it show? If im correct find returns an array, even if it's only 1 element, try with this

```
let followersArray = state.bugs.find(b => b.id === follower.bug_id).followers[0]
```